# Unable to capture view hierarchy while running UI Tests

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

Is it possible to view the UI Hierarchy when running the app through a UI Testing target?

I'm getting a white screen that says "Unable to capture view hierarchy. Check the console log for additional information"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have an issue because you're trying to Debug View Hierarchy of a wrong process. In UI testing, there are two processes. First is UI Test runner and second is your app. Both are attached but debug view is handling first process by default which is runner not the app. And you can't have view hierarchy for a runner. Thus, this message:
[image]
Please note which process is selected.

While the UI test is launched, you can change this selection to the app itself and hit the Debug View Hierarchy button which will successfully capture your app:
[image]

This is a little bit tricky though. The runner process is still active and will kill/relaunch your app even if it's in view debug mode. I could capture the hierarchy only while testing single test method.
It's likely you will have to put some waiting code to slow down the test execution to actually have time to hit the Debug View Hierarchy button.

Comment: in Xcode 9 beta 4, i have the correct process running but still get the same error when debugging a macOS app target. `Unable to capture view hierarchy.
Details:  Log Title: Data source expression execution failure.
Log Details: error evaluating expression “(id)[[DBGTargetHub sharedHub] performRequestWithRequestInBase64:] "Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff5f3ffff8).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.`" I think this a bug

Comment: I'm using Xcode Version 10.2.1, and I found after you switch to the correct process, pressing the View Debugger Hierarchy button again seems to do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

The UI view hierarchy (aka element subtree) can be viewed by printing the debug description of the application whilst a test is running.

```
print(app.debugDescription)
```

Important note: Sometimes the view hierarchy is one view "behind" when you print it because it is using the cached hierarchy. To account for this just take an action that will trigger a new snapshot of the view hierarchy before you print the debug description.

Comment: Yes but it's note quite the same thing. I'm looking for a way to use the View UI Hierarchy tool while running a UI Test